# Whats the best way to convert complex numpy array to an array of magnitudes?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

What I mean is something like:

```
mag(complex_array) = [ sqrt(complex.real * complex.real + complex.imag + complex.imag) for complex in complex_array ]
```

Is there a built-in function for this?

Comment: As in a numpy array? What about the 2-norm: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html ? there is also [`absolute`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html)...

Answer (score 2):

Just use `np.abs`:

```
>>> a = np.array([1+2j, 3+4j])
>>> np.abs(a)
array([2.23606798, 5.        ])
```

Comment: Cheers, was about to post an answer using `np.absolute`; they seem to do the same thing